# Holonomy of a curve in case of principal $U(1)$ bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles

Suppose $\pi : P\rightarrow M$ is principal $U(1)$ bundle. Let $\gamma$ be a loop in $M$ based at $x_0$ and write $iA$ as connection 1-form on $P$ where $A\in \Omega(P)$. Now define $hol_{\gamma}(A)\in U(1)$ as follows: let $\tilde{\gamma}$ be a horizontal lift of $\gamma$ with $\tilde{\gamma}(0)=p_0$ and $\pi(p_0)=x_0$. Then there is a unique element $hol_{\gamma}(A)$ in $U(1)$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(1)=p_0\cdot hol_{\gamma}(A)$ because the action is free and transitive.

I now want to calculate explicitly what is this number $hol_{\gamma}(A)$. I know already it has to be $hol_{\gamma}(A)=e^{i\int_{\gamma}A}$, but I have no idea how this is calculated as I am new to holonomy. Any hint is useful for me. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to compute it because you've given us none of the input data: the manifold $M$; the bundle $P$; or the loop $\gamma$. To calculate it, just do as it says: pick a horizontal lift etc.

Comment: @MikeMiller I dont understand what you mean. I want to show that $hol_{\gamma}(A)=e^{i\int_{\gamma}A}$. This should hold for all $U(1)$ principal bundles.

Comment: I'm super dense. Sorry! (Let's blame it on me just waking up. :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a loop $\gamma: S^1 \to M$, we can form the pullback bundle $\gamma^*P$ with pullback connection $\gamma^*A$. The holonomy of the pullback along the identity loop $S^1 \to S^1$ is the same as the holonomy of the original connection along the original loop $\gamma$. The bundle is now trivial (there's only one $U(1)$-bundle over $S^1$) and the connection form we'll still call $iA$. Consider the torus for now as $\Bbb R^2/2\pi\Bbb Z^2$.

If $iA$ is explicitly $f(t)dt + d\theta$, $d\theta$ the canonical 1-form on the circle fibers, the kernel at $T_{t,\theta}$ is those points of the form $(s,-f(t)s)$. We can then see explicitly that a horizontal lift is given by a curve with derivative $\eta'(t) = (1,-f(t))$; and we can explicitly write this down as $\eta(t) = (t, -\int_{0}^t f(s)ds)$. Thus $\eta(1) = (1, - \int_0^1 f(t)dt)$. Now this says that the holonomy is $$- \int_0^1 f(t)dt \pmod 1.$$ But that's just because here I'm considering the circle fiber to be $\Bbb R/2\pi \Bbb Z$; the canonical isomorphism $\Bbb R/2\pi \Bbb Z \to S^1$ is precisely the exponential map, giving you the desired holonomy $$e^{-\int_\gamma iA}.$$

Comment: Why is $iA$ of the form $f(t)dt+d\theta$? Can it not be more general $f(t)dt+g(\theta)d\theta?

Comment: @Badshah The definition of a connection form on a principle bundle demands that the connection form restrict to the canonical 1-form on each Lie group fiber.

Comment: @Badshah That's true, but recall that we're trying to traverse the circle in the positive direction, not the negative direction. If you go in the negative direction (that is, around the loop in the exact opposite way), your holonomy always changes by $\text{hol}(\gamma^{-1}) = \text{hol}(\gamma)^{-1}$. So it's important that we travel right.

Comment: Actually I am confused about the first statement that the holonomy of the pullback along the identity loop $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is the same as the holonomy of the original connection along the original loop. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: It's going to be some time before I'm back on a computer. This should be more or less a diagram chase - can you try it on your own first?

Comment: yes, I will try

Comment: I think I understand it using diagrams, unfortunately I dont know how to make diagrams using teX

Comment: @Badshah It's tricky to do. If you understand it, I'm happy :)

Comment: @MikeMiller Are you sure there is not a sign error in your Maurer-Cartan form? It seems like it would be more clear to take $iA=f(t)dt-d\theta$ so that $A=-if(t)+id\theta$. The substitution $f(t) \mapsto -f(t)$ gives the answer as anticipated by Badshah. Please let me know if I am missing something and sorry for reviving an old question!

Comment: Sorry in advance if this is trivial, but why is the only $U(1)$ principal bundle over $\mathbb{S}^1$ trivial?